# Can I configure Firefox to only show images when purposefully clicked on?

Tags: firefox, image-filter

I do not want to see any images of full or partial nudity or other sexual content while browsing the internet. I've found things like FoxFilter or AdBlock or which can help to remove these types of content if they are a kind of advertisement, but this does not block all the content that I do not want to see. I want to block every and any content – it can be a little picture, it can be a link to yoga exercises with a picture of girls wearing half body shirts or things like these. Is there any way?

Comment: Get your ISP to turn on any parental control features. You'll never permanently stop it, though...

Comment: I have edited your question pretty heavily to ensure that it remains an on-topic question for this site. There is no way to ensure that you will block all adult content, so the only solution is the one you already identified: to only allow content to be shown when you specifically click on it. I have therefore changed the question to fit that. If you'd like you can further [edit] it, just make sure it remains focused on the technical content, not your motivations for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off all images in Firefox, which is about the only way to do what you're asking without letting some content through. Open about:config, read the warning, click the "I'll be careful, I promise" button, search for permissions.default.image (it should be 1), and set it to 2. That'll disable all images from loading and prevent you from ever seeing anything that could ever be considered pornographic aside from ASCII porn.

Answer (score 1):

These suggestions (mine and Aron's) affect all visual objects of a certain type (Aron's affects all pictures, my suggestion affects all Flash objects), not just ones that may have certain types of content.  No software has managed to affect only images that are too tantalizing for some people's preferences and also leave other images unaffected.  For that, the best you can do is to try to use "content-based filtering", although such techniques are imperfect (and may be very far from perfect).

Well, let's see just what can be easily done.

Aron's answer covers images.  However, you also asked about Flash objects, so I'm  adding this as a second answer.

In the current versions of Firefox, Flash can be disabled usually, but then enabled upon request.  To do this, press Alt-T (_T_ools), A (_A_dd-ons).  That's in Microsoft Windows: I know Firefox for Linux has some menu difference (Tools, Options is Edit, Preferences).  Or, go to your address bar and type about:addons (which will bring you to the same screen).

Then click on Plugins (in the left frame).  Find Flash (on my system it is called "Shockwave Flash"), and choose "Ask to Activate".

With that setting changed, when you load pages, the flash objects generally look basically like a grey box with a button asking you for permission to load flash objects on the page.  I say "generally" because there is an option to permit a certain site to just always have permission.  If you click on the button, another little confirmation screen thing will appear near the upper-left corner of the browser window, confirming your intent.

This probably reduces your exposure to certain types of Internet-based attacks, reduces your exposure to some advertisements, and may have other benefits like reducing the amount of work your computer needs to do (which could affect battery life for laptops).

(My information is based on Firefox for Microsoft Windows, except where otherwise noted.)

Answer (score 0):

this really is a softwarerecs.com question , but let me answer here . the OP is asking for a client side solution to detect and mute pornographic images , and interactively click to display if user believe a false positive . this package http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/ claims to fit the need .

---

for a generic problem , **to mute all images untill clicked upon** . we can write a custom css stylesheet on the html `img` element , replace it with a button , then hook a javascript that put the original image back . [a reference implementation can be found in any popular flash blocker](http://5digits.org/plugins/flashblock.js) , which mute the different html element , but with identical mechanism .